# devops test unit test plans automated

Tags: automated-tests, devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

How to check why my tests are aborted?
Here my pipeline settings:[image: first task]
[image: second task]

I get this info after running release via TestPlans with given test name.
`2022-11-04T08:31:31.5821815Z Received the command : Stop 2022-11-04T08:31:31.5822525Z TestExecutionHost.ProcessCommand. Stop Command handled 2022-11-04T08:31:31.5829836Z SliceFetch Aborted. Moving to the TestHostEnd phase 2022-11-04T08:31:31.6329595Z Please use this link to analyze the test run : XXXX 2022-11-04T08:31:31.6330550Z Test run '1003094' is in 'Aborted' state with 'Total Tests' : 1 and 'Passed Tests' : 0. 2022-11-04T08:31:31.6370139Z ##[error]Test run is aborted. Logging details of the run logs. 2022-11-04T08:31:31.6381874Z ##[error]System.Exception: The test run was aborted, failing the task. 2022-11-04T08:31:31.6925500Z ##########################################################################`

I tried to change Test platform version 2017/2019 but it always gives the same error.

I created special test scenarious which do nothing:

```
 [Fact(DisplayName ="DoNothing")]
        public void DoNothingTest()
        {
          
        }
```

Full logs:
[Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfsDd.png)

Comment: Test execution can abort due to several reasons such as bad test code, errors in the source under test, or environmental issues.So could you kindly tell whether the test run successfully in local Visual Studio? Do you use self-hosted agent or MS-hosted agent? What about using a local run successfully (not empty) simple test run in release pipeline for a try? Will it successfully?We would like to check the error log for further investigation.

Comment: Hi does the issue still exit? What about if you tried to use other format empty test like this for a try? Will it run successfully? [TestMethod] public void TestMethod1() { Console.WriteLine("Hello World!"); }